# recent user stats sorting ignores the year part of the date

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Looking at my personal "stats" tab sorting by "recent" I get a question with updates from Aug 2008 before an question from Aug 2009. Seems like it is ignoring the year part of the date.

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/7332/sobug.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/7332/sobug.png)

Comment: I have considered it, but ultimately decided I would regret it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the question is from 2008, the most recent activity on that question is from 2009, by the community user. I believe the `newest` tab would show the questions you asked from newest to oldest. The `recent` tab shows the questions you have asked sorted by date of most recent activity, which includes cleanup activities performed by the community user.

Comment: question 249293 doesn't seem to have any recent activity

Comment: The community user probably automatically bumped it up so that it would get some more views.

Comment: @harlev, I don't know what the community user does/did, but it seems it did something on August 11, 2009.

Comment: The community user will routinely go through the old posts and elevate them for a brief moment to try and get more answers on them.

Answer (score 0):

Community bumps two unanswered questions per hour.

Remember, our definition of "unanswered" is that a question has no *upvoted* answers.